# How to delete registry properties with randomized names

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove junk registry items left from adware in several machines. The adware created registry keys in the following path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\

Property: a random name that is different from machine to machine

Value: a malicious string that is the same from machine to machine

```
Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\System\Controlset001\Services | 
  Get-ItemProperty |
    Where-Object {$_.ValueName -eq "Value"} |
      Remove-ItemProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I´ve tried the method above to delete keys when I know the subkey and properties, but since the property is random I am getting no results. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative script for get-itemproperty:

```
# get-itemproperty2.ps1
param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$key)
process { 
  $key.getvaluenames() |
  foreach {
    $value = $_
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Path = $key -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
        'HKCU:' -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:'
      Name = $Value
      Value = $Key.GetValue($Value)
      Type = $Key.GetValueKind($Value)
    }
  }
}
```

So you can do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\System\Controlset001\Services | .\Get-ItemProperty2 |
  Where Value -eq MyValue | Remove-ItemProperty -Whatif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `Get-ItemProperty` isn't required for your task (and there is *no* need to re-implement a variation of it, the way that the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58386661/45375) does).

Instead, filter by the output from the `.GetValue()` method applied to each subkey of the registry path of interest, **assuming a known property name (registry value name)**:

```
# Specify whatever fixed value the malware stored in the 'ImagePath'
# property of the randomly named keys.
$propValue = '...'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath HKLM:\System\ControlSet001\Services |
  Where-Object { $_.GetValue('ImagePath') -eq $propValue } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: [Common parameter `-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) *previews* the operation; remove it to perform the actual operation.</sup>

- `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath HKLM:\System\ControlSet001\Services` enumerates all subkeys of the specified path.
- `Where-Object { $_.GetValue('ImagePath') -eq $propValue }` selects only those subkey(s) whose `ImagePath` property has the specified value.
- `Remove-Item` then removes the selected subkey(s).

---

If you want to **find data (a property value) among *all* properties (registry values) of the input keys**, you can use the following approach:

```
$propValue = '...'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath HKLM:\System\ControlSet001\Services |
  Where-Object { 
    foreach ($name in $_.GetValueNames()) { 
      if ($_.GetValue($name) -eq $propValue) { return $true } } 
    }
  }| Remove-Item -WhatIf
```